# How read data from xml string in C#

Tags: c#

I get this XML string for my web page, how can I retrieve data from that XML and assign values to labels in my web page?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<things>
    <bat>201400000586</bat>
    <status>Y</status>
    <totalAmount>3090</totalAmount>
    <billno>P2355</billno>
    <ReceiveDate>27/04/2015 06:22:18 PM</ReceiveDate>
</things>
```

Comment: You will need to parse the XML. I am not sure why you have put C# tag to this question. But if you want to do it in C# you can use XMLReader.

Comment: Interesting that this is marked as "exact duplicate."  Between the "duplicate" and this answer are 5 different solutions to the same problem.  That is why I started my answer with "There are different ways to do this."

Answer (score 0):

Firstly load the Xml Doc using XMLDocument

```
  XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(filePath);
  XElement rootElm = doc.Element("things")
```

Now using linq you can fetch IENumerable

```
IEnumerable<XElement> childList = from Y in rootElm.Root.Elements()
                                                  select Y;
```

Now ou can loop through list items

```
 foreach (XElement elm in childList)
  {
   //Here you can access elements this way
   Console.log(elm.Element("status").Value);
    ..........
  }
```

Here you can even edit the contents in xml file and save them.
Assign the values for the XElement type elements in the loop

```
doc.Save(filePath);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to do this.  Here is one.

You'll need to add "using System.Xml.XPath;"

```
        XPathDocument doc = new XPathDocument(Server.MapPath("~/XMLFile1.xml"));

        XPathNavigator nav = doc.CreateNavigator();

        XPathExpression exp = nav.Compile(@"/things");

        foreach (XPathNavigator item in nav.Select(exp))
        {

            label1.Text = item.SelectSingleNode("bat").ToString();
            label2.Text = item.SelectSingleNode("totalAmount").ToString();

        }
```

Or you can load it as a string, then use EITHER XmlElement or XmlNode with such a simple XML structure.

```
        XmlDocument m_xml = new XmlDocument();
        m_xml.LoadXml(@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8"" standalone=""yes"" ?><things><bat>201400000586</bat><status>Y</status><totalAmount>3090</totalAmount><billno>P2355</billno><ReceiveDate>27/04/2015 06:22:18 PM</ReceiveDate></things>");

        XmlNode node_bat = m_xml.SelectSingleNode("//things/bat");
        XmlNode node_totalAmount = m_xml.SelectSingleNode("//things/totalAmount");

        XmlElement node_bat1 = m_xml.DocumentElement["bat"];
        XmlElement node_totalAmount1 = m_xml.DocumentElement["totalAmount"];

        label1.Text = node_bat1.InnerText;
        label2.Text = node_totalAmount1.InnerText;
```

Comment: here you are reading data from XML file, but in my case i will get only XML string from some other page to my page

Comment: your code is working, thank u